# Python: Cyclic indexing of lists

Tags: python

Take the following example :

```
a = range(10)
```

We can proceed through the list from left to right as follows: `a[0], a[1], ...., a[9]`
Or in the other way around with negative indexes: `a[-1], a[-2], a[-3], ....`

It is also possible to index a range, e.g. `a[from:to-1]`

Because I know that the index of the last element is -1, I would say (theoretical thought) that `a[0:0]` should deliver the whole list, since `a[0:0-1]` is from 0 to -1 (including -1).

This is wrong, but why? It makes more sense to me than `a[0:]` (whole list)
EDIT:

So to make it simple (I'm just wondering!^^):
`a[from:to-1]` means: get elements from `from` to `to`. Ok, we want to get the whole list, means (following this reasoning): `a[0:0]` (which is the empty list), but hey 0-1 is the last element, right?

Comment: What is the question? Why `a[0:-1]` doesn't work, because it does

Comment: First, it's already idiomatic to get a slice (copy) of the whole list by `a[:]`.  Second, be careful what you mean by *cyclic*.  If it's "logical" for `a[0:0]` to be `a[0], a[1], ..., a[9]`, then wouldn't it also be logical for `a[0:1]` to be `a[0], a[1], ..., a[9], a[0]`?

Comment: @John: `a[0:1]` is `a[0:0]` also the (math) interval [0,0] which is empty. But `a[0:0]` is  `[0:-1]` which is the (math )interval [0,9]. So maybe the word cyclic is not precise here, but still I don't think your example make sense.

Comment: I don't understand the first two sentences of your previous comment. If we're talking about math intervals, we should be talking about half-open intervals like [x,y). But anyway, if your "logic" is that since 0 is the successor to -1, then `a[0:0]` should be equal to `a[0:-1]` plus the next element, then your logic is also saying that `a[0:1]` should be equal to `a[0:0]` plus the next element.

Comment: @John: Yeah `a[x:y]` is the interval [x,y) or the interval [x,y-1]. So what happens when you consider in the closed interval the case x=y=0, knowing that -1 := last element?

Comment: But slicing isn't generalizable to arbitrary x and y in a "mathy" way. Slicing is a specific construct in Python that behaves in a very specific and well-defined (but not "mathematically pure") way. I find it helpful not to look at closed or open intervals, but just to think of the index numbers as cursors, which sit *between* elements. If elements are housed in square cells, then index 2 is a cursor to the left boundary of element 2 (equivalent to the right boundary of element 1).

Comment: @Johny: I agree with you. I just was confused when I thought of it in a mathematical way.

Comment: There is a great picture of what I'm talking about toward the end of the section on strings in the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). There it makes it quite clear that the start and end parameters are not treated differently. An index is an index, and you just grab all the elements between the indices, period. See also the discussion in @jamylak's answer why we can't have two different behaviors for 0.

Answer (score 2):

The indexing isn't "cyclic":

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
a[2]  # 2
a[3]  # IndexError, not 0
a[-3] # 0
a[-4] # IndexError, not 2
```

`-3` as an index is just a shorthand for **`length-3`.**

Answer (score 1):

`range` doesn't subtract `1` from the stop parameter. It increases (or decreases - let's assume it increases in this example) until it is greater than or equal to `stop` (since it is exclusive of the end point) and then it returns. `a[0:0]` should not deliver the whole array because you told it go from `0` to `0` non-inclusive of the end point `0`, which is an empty range.

Comment: Note that if Python had signed integer zeros (similar to IEEE 754), something like `a[0:-0]` could be distinguished from `a[0:0]` in order to give you the whole list.

Comment: @chepner that would be nice

Comment: @jamylak -- I disagree.  That would be confusing.

Comment: @mgilson I can't really make up my mind on whether that would be good or not... It's annoying how you have to pull out `a[0:len(a)-n]` to support `n` being `0` when you want `a[:-n]`. At first glance it seems unpythonic but it makes sense

Comment: @mgilson I agree; an additional `-0` would have so many implications on other parts in the language. And to add it just for slicing does not really make sense, when there is already `a[:]` to get you a copy (*“There should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it.”*).

Comment: @poke see my example case above

Comment: @jamylak Doesn’t change the fact that it wouldn’t make sense to have a `-0` in the first place. `-0` would be equal to `0` and then the slice would already not work, because the slice parameters are expressions, and there cannot be a different behavior for `a[0:0]` and `a[0:-0]` when `0 == -0`. So you would have to make them inequal, and then the whole language would break as two zeros make arithmetic a lot more complicated (when does an expression yield `0`, when `-0`? etc.).

Comment: @poke I was just saying that it kinda makes sense in slicing. You are correct about it screwing up the entire language

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you slice, positive numbers are counted from the beginning of the list whereas negative numbers are counted from the end.  When you slice you you take everything from the first index (inclusive) up to the second index (not inclusive).  If there is nothing in that range, you get an empty list.

```
a[0:0]
```

would be a very confusing API for a lot of people.  Sometimes it is helpful to think of what python is actually doing:

```
a[slice(0,None)]
```

which says that we start from 0 but there is no upper bound which is pythons way of saying that the upper bound is infinite -- therefore you take all the elements.

Of course, this could also be acomplsihed by:

```
a[:]
```

In which case there is no lower bound either ...

Answer (score 1):

The slice `s[i:j]` is just defined that way:

> - If `i` or `j` is negative, the index is relative to the end of the string: `len(s) + i` or `len(s) + j` is substituted. But note that `-0` is still `0`.
> - The slice of `s` from `i` to `j` is defined as the sequence of items with index `k` such that `i <= k < j`. If `i` or `j` is greater than `len(s)`, use `len(s)`. If `i` is omitted or None, use `0`. If `j` is omitted or `None`, use `len(s)`. If `i` is greater than or equal to `j`, the slice is empty.

So `a[0:0]` gives you an empty list, because `i` is equal to `j`. And `a[i:j]` for negative `j` is translated to `a[i:range(a) + j]` before the slicing happens, so `a[0:-1]` itself wouldn’t be a valid slice (as `i < j` is not true), but as the translation happens before, it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking about reverse iteration, not cyclic indexing.  Reverse iteration is simple, using either slicing or `reversed()`.

```
for i in range(10)[::-1]:
    print i
for i in reversed(range(10)):
    print i
```

Reversed is pretty self-explanatory.  For slicing, the third value in the colon-delimited list is the step.  If you specify a negative step, it will iterate backwards through the list.  If you specify no start or stop, it will iterate through the entire list.